# GPU to Thunderbolt 3 Using AIC and Riser

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, pci-express

I got a weird/crazy one here, I want an eGPU for my laptop, the enclosures are all overkill for any GPU I would use (AMD Radeon Pro WX5100). So, I found this [AIC](https://www.newegg.com/asrock-model-thunerbolt-3-aic-r2-0-pci-express-to-thunderbolt/p/N82E16815548006) then found a female to female GPU riser. The question is, could it work, using the AIC backwards?

Comment: You should know the answer if you search enough. Assuming it works...where are you getting your 75W supply for the WX5100? Enclosures are a clean AIO solution and not overkill in any way.

Comment: I would like something more portable than most 550W enclosures and 350W enclosures are rare. I thought about power, but I could probably find a workaround.

Comment: Did you check out https://egpu.io/best-egpu-buyers-guide/ ?  If you're really going at it openly, look out for the ADT-Link R43SG-TB3

Answer (score 0):

I have determined from Natsu Kage that there is a solution for people like me who are crazy. The solution is an ADT Link R43SG TB3 adapter. Thank you, Natsu for pointing me in the right direction.